# SQL - Select all when filter value is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query in my ASP.net web app that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Records] WHERE ([title] LIKE '%' + @title + '%')
```

@title, of course, is the value of a text box on the page.

My question is, why, when the text box is empty, does this return nothing? And how can I make it return everything, like logic tells me it ought to?

Comment: put a breakpoint and check the actual query that is being sent to the database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [Records] 
WHERE @title IS NULL OR LEN(@Title) = 0 OR ([title] LIKE '%' + @title + '%')
```

Comment: @John Saunders: If it's SQL Server, then you have to use `RTRIM(LTRIM(@Title))` - there's no TRIM() function in TSQL :(

Comment: @Mitch: maybe LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@Title)))?  @OMG: did a "late man's edit".

Comment: OK, this works when I query the database manually, but for some reason it doesn't work with the web form... I guess that's a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The most sargable option, short of using dynamic SQL, is to use an IF statement and two queries:

```
IF LEN(@Title) > 0

  SELECT r.*
    FROM RECORDS r
   WHERE r.title LIKE '%'+ @Title +'%'

ELSE

  SELECT r.*
    FROM RECORDS r
```

The SQL Server 2005+ dynamic SQL version would resemble:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
   SET @SQL = 'SELECT r.*
                 FROM RECORDS r 
                WHERE 1 = 1' --will be optimized out, easier to add clauses

   SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE LEN(@Title)
                       WHEN 0 THEN ''
                       ELSE ' AND r.name LIKE ''%''+ @Title +''%'' '   
                     END

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Title VARCHAR(#)', @Title

END
```

Unlike `EXEC`, `sp_executesql` will cache the query plan.  You can read more about it in [the Blessing & Curse of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the value of @title is holding null or a single space?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM [Records] WHERE (isnull(@title,'') = '' or [title] LIKE '%' + @title + '%')
```

Or do a check for an empty title in the client code, pass NULL if so, and do a condition: "@title is null or...".

Answer (score 0):

NULL plus anything is NULL so while you might expect to get '%%' you are actually getting NULL. Since nothing is LIKE NULL (things IS NULL instead) you get nothing. You might try something like WHERE [TITLE] LIKE ISNULL('%' + @title + '%', '%');
If the first argument to ISNULL is NULL, it returns the second arg.