# ASP.Net Textbox control doesn't return NULL when it is empty

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

In reference to this question that I just asked -- [SQL - Select all when filter value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451579/sql-select-all-when-filter-value-is-empty) -- it appears that for some reason, an empty `TextBox`'s value is not being fed to SQL Server as NULL, as it ought to be.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What makes you think an empty text box should become `NULL` to SQL Server?

Comment: Well, logic would state that when a text box is empty, its value is NULL. I mean, what else would its value be?

Comment: `null` in a programming language isn't necessarily related to `NULL` in a relational database.

Comment: You also might want to say _how_ you're sending the data to SQL Server.

Comment: Re: how I'm sending the data to SQL Server: ASP.net AJAX. The DataList is in an UpdatePanel that has TextBox.TextChanged set as one of its triggers. This will all have to change, seeing as I obviously need to do some C#-level stuff to the Textbox value.

Comment: How are you binding the DataList to the database? DataLists, TextBoxes, Ajax and UpdatePanel are just UI technologies. Are you using Linq-To-Sql? The SqlDataSource?

Comment: The SqlDataSource has a SelectCommand. the DataList is databound to the SqlDataSource.

Comment: @iansinke: let's follow the data from the textbox to SQL Server. How does the data get from the textbox to SQL Server? Parameters?

Comment: Yeah, one of the parameters in the SQL query is the textbox value

Comment: I think it's better don't insert empty value into database, if the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 16):

An empty text box will contain `string.Empty`, not `null`.

From the [TextBox.Text documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx):

> **Property Value**
>   Type: System.String
>   The text displayed in the TextBox control. **The default is an empty string ("").**

If you want to make sure it goes to the database as `null`, then convert it on the way in:

```
string value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) ? tb.Text: null;
```

Answer (score 4):

just to enlighten you :)

this is from reflector:

```
public virtual string Text
{
    get
    {
        string str = (string) this.ViewState["Text"];
        if (str != null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["Text"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing us what the Framework actually does, and eliminating any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any C#.

Simply set the parameters ConvertEmptyStringToNull property to true, eg:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ObjectDataSourceExample" TypeName="Example.ExampleTableAdapter" SelectMethod="GetDataBySomething">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Something" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" ControlID="tbSomething" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Anyway, the default value is true: "true if the value that the Parameter  is bound to should be converted to nullNothingnullptra null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) when it is String..::.Empty; otherwise, false. The default value is true." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.convertemptystringtonull.aspx

Comment: Is the parameter of your query set as nullable in your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

"""Property Value
Type: System.String
The text displayed in the TextBox control. The default is an empty string ("")."""

Aaronaught is correct.

Null is a very loosely used term and shouldn't be, and can easily be confused with 'Nothing' which is far better to use in programming. A textbox.text value will never be null, it will be "". Nothing refers to whether you have initialized the string variable or not. sooooo

```
the textbox itself could = Nothing
the textbox.text can only equal "" (or string.empty - function does the same thing) if the textbox isnot nothing
```

It's a general good rule of thumb to use string.empty or "" when referring to whether a string contains any characters

Obviously the Paramater you use in ur sqlcommand needs to be null or not so...

In VB:

```
If TextBox.Text = "" Then
VariableUsedInSqlCommand = Nothing
End If
```

From her you can set the default paramater value in SP or Inline SqlCommand to be Null, so when it recieves a paramter that Is Nothing, it reverts the paramater to = Null

In Stored Procedure (if you're sending the textbox.text value directly to a SP Paramater):

```
If (@Paramater = "") 
Begin

end
else
begin

end
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the default parameter value in the ASP code to `null`.

Comment: I don't get it...I somehow got 10 points for this, then negative 2.  I'm guessing it was voted up, then voted down?